# How pass password and username encrypt in Dio flutter?

Tags: flutter, authentication, dart, odoo

In my application I use a DIO flutter library for login and for make a question in my db.
This is my configuration

```
 static String BASE_URL = "http://localhost:8069/";
  static Dio dio = Dio()
    ..options.baseUrl = BASE_URL
    ..options.connectTimeout = 5000
    ..options.receiveTimeout = 100000;
```

For login I have:

```
Map<String, dynamic> data = {
              "params": {
                'db': "name_db",
                'login': 'name_xxxxx',
                'password': 'password_xxxx'
              }
            };
            dio.interceptors.add(CookieManager(cookieJar));
            globals.dio = dio;
            Response response = await dio.post("/web/session/authenticate",
                data: json.encode(data),
                options:
                    Options(headers: {"Content-Type": "application/json"}));
```

Is there a way to pass the encrypted login and password so as not to write the username and password in clear text in the code of my app?

Comment: I would do this the other way, write in clear text an encrypted version of your login & password which you would decode to have it in your data.

Answer (score 0):

You should receive password as plain text and make **hash of password** in **backend** and save the **hash** in **DB**. and during login take plain text as password and then make its hash then compare it with DB's password hash.
to create hash you have to use a secret key. search in google for what ever language you have used in backend.

alternatively you can try **RSA** . It is a public-key cryptosystem, which is widely used for secure data transmission. used public-key for encoding and use private-key for decoding.

**NB:** This is totally related to architecture,  Dio has nothing do with it.

Comment: I see. The problem is that the login you see in the code is general for all users. I log in to then be able to query the db, in fact the various users who will use the app will not have a personalized login. I wanted a way to not write clear username and password in my code

Comment: You are talking about a static username and password , right ?  It is not secure !  but you can create **base64** string  and save them in code. before sending request decode it .